# Blazor parameter giving Cannot use Local Variable before it is declared error

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have some components that accept a Name string and will display different information based on the name passed them. Some of these components have no issues, but some of them will flag a CS0841 error code on the usage.

> Error (active) CS0841  Cannot use local variable 'Name' before it is declared      \Pages\Awards\Tech  \Pages\Awards\Tech\Profile.razor    4

This one Works

```
<!-- Block1 -->
<div class="flip-card @Classes" onclick="@callback">
    <div>
        <Images Name="@Name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2><NameInfo Name="@Name" ReturnVal="Name"/></h2>
        <h3>@year</h3>
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name{get;set;}
    [Parameter]
    public string? Classes{ get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string[] list{ get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public int year{ get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<int> yearCallback{ get; set; }


    public async Task callback()
    {
        await yearCallback.InvokeAsync(year);
    }
}
```

---

But this one doesn't

```
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="prof-container">
    <div class="year-close">
        <h2>@Year</h2>
        <h1><NameInfo Name="@Name" ReturnVal="Name" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portrait">
        <Images Name="@Name"/>
    </div>
    <button class="CloseProfile" onclick="@callback"> X </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Year{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> clear{ get; set; }

    public async Task callback()
    {
        await clear.InvokeAsync("");
    }
}
```

I've searched the error code information, looked at several other questions on here, the closest seemingly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279748/cannot-use-local-variable-before-it-is-declared-asp-net). However, this doesn't explain why I'm getting this error. It applies to all instances of calling my parameters, in block2, but not in block1.

Block1 compiles with no issues, links with no issues and runs fine.
Block2 throws errors and prevents successful build.

What am I missing that's causing this to happen?

Edit: Corrected EventCallback to EventCallback and added ("") to InvokeAsync in block2

Comment: Post the actual full compilation error. The error is clear - some code tried to use a variable that hasn't been declared yet. The snippets you posted aren't complete though. Perhaps the error was produced by some missing part of the component. Another possibility is that some *other* error in the component resulted in incomplete source generation.

Comment: I posted the one that iterates for each (at)Name instance and (at)Year.

Comment: There's no iteration in the question. Post the actual full error and actual code that causes it. One reason for the error can be using a loop variable outside the loop.

Comment: That's the error. CS0841 is the error that comes up. It comes up 3 times. Twice for Name and once for Year. By iterates, I mean the error comes up multiple times for each instance of the references parameter. Pardon the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm uncertain as to the source of the issue.
I did, however, determine a fix that allowed it to build again.

1. In HTML remove all references to parameters.

```cs
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="prof-container">
    <div class="year-close">
        <h2></h2>
        <h1><NameInfo Name="" ReturnVal="Name" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portrait">
        <Images Name="@Name"/>
    </div>
    <button class="CloseProfile" onclick=""> X </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Year{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> clear{ get; set; }

    public async Task callback()
    {
        await clear.InvokeAsync("");
    }
}
```

2. Cut the code block entirely. Save and build. The same error still appears.

```cs
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="prof-container">
    <div class="year-close">
        <h2></h2>
        <h1><NameInfo Name="" ReturnVal="Name" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portrait">
        <Images Name=""/>
    </div>
    <button class="CloseProfile" onclick=""> X </button>
</div>
```

3. Paste or Retype the code block

```cs
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="prof-container">
    <div class="year-close">
        <h2></h2>
        <h1><NameInfo Name="" ReturnVal="Name" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portrait">
        <Images Name=""/>
    </div>
    <button class="CloseProfile" onclick=""> X </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Year{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> clear{ get; set; }

    public async Task callback()
    {
        await clear.InvokeAsync("");
    }
}
```

4. Save and close the IDE
5. Add references back into the HTML.

```cs
<!-- Block2 -->
<div class="prof-container">
    <div class="year-close">
        <h2>@Year</h2>
        <h1><NameInfo Name="@Name" ReturnVal="Name" /></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="portrait">
        <Images Name="@Name"/>
    </div>
    <button class="CloseProfile" onclick="@callback"> X </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? Year{ get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> clear{ get; set; }

    public async Task callback()
    {
        await clear.InvokeAsync("");
    }
}
```

Code looks identical, but it builds without error now.

Comment: VS2022?  Did you copy and paste Razor files in the Solution Explorer pane?

Comment: VS2022, yes! Copy and paste just the text, files remained the same

Comment: NP.  It's one area to be careful.  I always copy and rename files in File Explorer as I've had many problems like yours over time.